# Описание "дерева" Oracle в Django models.py

Tags: oracle, python, дерево, django

Доброго времени суток. Помогите, пожалуйста, со следующим вопросом.

Необходимо описать модель дерева в Django. Используемая БД - Oracle.

Описываю так:

```
class TelDivisions(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'tel_divisions'
```

но таким образом **parent** ссылается сам на себя. Каким образом сделать так, чтобы он ссылался на столбец **id** данной таблицы?

Думал может получиться вот так:

```
class TelDivisions(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(TelDivisions, db_column='id', blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'tel_divisions'
```

но команда **python manage.py validate** выявила:

```
parent = models.ForeignKey(TelDivisions, db_column='id', blank=True)
NameError: name 'TelDivisions' is not defined
```

Что, собственно, логично. Как же быть?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Рекомендую Вам использовать [django-mtpp](http://django-mptt.github.com/django-mptt/). Она была создана как раз для отображения древовидных структур в реляционной модели.

А что касается вашего вопроса:

```
parent = models.ForeignKey('self', db_column='id', blank=True)
```

И всё должно заработать. Ссылаться надо на самого себя через self. Данный пример описан в django docs.

И ещё одно. Если не укажите null = True, то не сможете создать ни одного корновего экземпляра (т.е. такого, у которого нет родителя). Итого:

```
parent = models.ForeignKey('self', db_column='id', blank=True, null = True)
```

db_column='id' можно не указывать, т.к. он и так будет ссылаться по умолчанию на ключевое поле таблицы, т.е. id.

Answer (score 2):

Правильно делаешь в первом варианте, в базе будет столбик `parent_id` типа `integer`.

Гляньте статейку и комментарии почитайте, там есть полезные ссылочки, сам на днях разбирался с этим вопросом: [деревья в джанго-шаблонах](http://softwaremaniacs.org/blog/2009/09/21/trees-in-django-templates/)

Если дерево многоуровневое, то mtpp все рекомендуют, но если один уровень вложенности как у меня, то я без дополнительных библиотек обошелся.

Comment: Да, было дело, тоже натыкался на эту статейку. Спасибо)